# import and module.exports in Vuex module show Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object

Tags: vue.js, vuex-modules

i have a vuex module by Vue CLI

```
import { Sev } from "../api";
const modules = {
  actions: {
    getData() {
      Sev();
    }
  }
};

module.exports = modules;
```

and i got an error in browser console

```
test.js?5df4:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.eval (test.js?5df4:10)
    at eval (test.js:12)
    at Module../src/config/store_modules/test.js (app.js:1263)
```

then i change the code to

```
import { Sev } from "../api";
// const modules = {
export default {
  actions: {
    getData() {
      Sev();
    }
  }
};
// module.exports = modules;
```

then work well. But i don't know what different. is it a bug ?

Comment: Depends on your setup. Why is the question tagged with node.js? Do you use Vue CLI? Do you have specific config? The error is caused by the way Webpack does module interoperability. `module.exports` and `export default` could be interchangeable for other setups but for yours they aren't.

Comment: Thank you for comment, sorry i tagged wrong i'm new
I use Vue CLI to created project and have not specific config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VueJS is browser code and use ES6 modules

```
import xxx from './path/to/xxx';
export xxx;
export default xxx;
```

while CommonJS is used by NodeJS and is completely different

```
const yyy = require('./path/to/yyy');
module.exports = { yyy };
exports.zzz = yyy;
```

You're writing Vue code so you must use ES6 modules and the import/export syntax, the `module` object doesn't behave as you'd expect in ES6

Comment: This isn't true. `module` object exists because it's created by a bundler. You can clearly see this in error message. There's a lot of scenarios when CommonJS modules and `module.exports` work in client-side apps when they are handled correctly with module interop. It's correct that ES modules should be used with Vue but the OP already knew it.

Comment: Yes I know;) I said "the module object doesn't exist as you'd expect" but I meant "the module object doesn't behave as you'd expect"